# "javac: file not found" if path is quoted

Tags: wildcard, javac

I built an application to compile and run java files and it was running completely ok.

Since it is the user to choose the path of java files to be compiled and executed, i quote the path, so that it can contains white spaces and special characters. Like this:

```
javac "C:\test project\*.java"
```

Now, i tried out in another computer and now i am having this error:

```
javac: file not found: C:\test project\*.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

If i remove quotes and there is no spaces or special characters in path it works, but for the example above, that contains a white space, i get this error:

```
javac: invalid flag: C:\test 
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

I've read some threads about this, but i couldn't figured out the solution. Anybody has a clue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Try quoting **only** the path and add the *.java **after** the quote. For example:

```
javac "C:\test project"\*.java
```

I've had a script in my test env with the same pattern, which stopped working today. After some research I've seen that the only change is that I've updated from JDK7 update 7 to update 17, and when I go back to update 7 it's working again. Seems that there's a new bug which was introduced somewhere in between. After some trial and error I came up with this workaround, which works for both the old and new javac.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is meaningful to the shell, not to the compiler. When you put the `*` in the quotes, you are passing it to the compiler, not allowing the shell to expand it. you need to quote the spaces without quoting the star.

However, you'd be far better off using a proper build tool such as ant or maven.